# Collapsing and set Visible elements on a Marquee with Background Worker

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a Marquee with elements by status (**green, yellow, red**), actually they are three of them separted by **status**, here is a demo of what i have so far. The program is small

[image]

**The logic**

If one element is status green it must not be visible in status yellow and red, if it is status yellow must not be visible in green and red and finally if it is red it must not be visible in status green and yellow.

The problem i am faceing is the update of the elements of a Marquee using a background worker to update the ui, the marquee doesn't display the elements and movent correctly. I am updating the width of a wrapperpanel who holds the elements and i am updating the Canvas.Left property of the wrapper panel in the way it can start moving from the begining of the canvas. But sometimes the panel doesn't start appearing at the begining and sometime disappear for a time, or dissapear before it ends. The status of the elements is set by a call to a database to get the three possible ststus Green is Connected Yellow is Warning and Red is DisConnected

Here is my code

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvasConnected" Grid.Row="0" Background="YellowGreen" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="canvasConnected_SizeChanged">
        <WrapPanel x:Name="panelConnected" Width="{Binding PanelConnectedWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  Height="130" Canvas.Left="{Binding CanvasLeftConnected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Loaded="tb_Loaded">
            <WrapPanel.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="slide">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=panelConnected}" Duration="{Binding TimeConnected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                  Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny"
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </WrapPanel.Resources>
            <WrapPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny" X="0"/>
            </WrapPanel.RenderTransform>
            <WrapPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="WrapPanel.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </WrapPanel.Triggers>
            <TextBlock x:Name="macaracuayConnected" Width="620" Text="MACARACUAY&#x0a;10.0.1.11; 1.1.1.4" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="guacaraConnected" Width="620" Text="GUACARA&#x0a;10.0.1.11; 1.1.1.5" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia03Connected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 03&#x0a;192.168.0.1; 1.1.1.6" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia03_02_Connected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 03&#x0a;192.168.0.2; 1.1.1.6" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia10Connected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 10&#x0a;192.168.0.1; 1.1.1.7" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia10_02_Connected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 10&#x0a;192.168.0.2; 1.1.1.7" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia20Connected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 20&#x0a;192.168.0.1; 1.1.1.8" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia20_02_Connected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 20&#x0a;192.168.0.2; 1.1.1.8" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="port1Connected" Width="620" Text="PORT 1 (Metro Ethernet)&#x0a;200.11.138.188" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="port2Connected" Width="620" Text="PORT 2 (Metro Ethernet)&#x0a;201.249.182.250" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="fibra200Connected" Width="620" Text="FIBRA 200Mbps&#x0a;201.249.133.34" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="fibra10Connected" Width="620" Text="FIBRA 10Mbps&#x0a;200.50.195.130" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Visible"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Canvas>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvasWarning" Grid.Row="2" Background="Yellow" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="canvasWarning_SizeChanged">
        <WrapPanel x:Name="panelWarning" Width="{Binding PanelWarningWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="130" Canvas.Left="{Binding CanvasLeftWarning, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Loaded="tb_Loaded">
        <WrapPanel.Resources>
            <Storyboard x:Key="slide2">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=panelWarning}" Duration="{Binding TimeWarning, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                  Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny2"
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </WrapPanel.Resources>
        <WrapPanel.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny2" X="0"/>
        </WrapPanel.RenderTransform>
        <WrapPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="WrapPanel.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide2}" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </WrapPanel.Triggers>
            <TextBlock x:Name="macaracuayWarning" Width="620" Text="MACARACUAY&#x0a;10.0.1.11; 1.1.1.4" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="guacaraWarning" Width="620" Text="GUACARA&#x0a;10.0.1.11; 1.1.1.5" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia03Warning" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 03&#x0a;192.168.0.1; 1.1.1.6" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia03_02_Warning" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 03&#x0a;192.168.0.2; 1.1.1.6" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia10Warning" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 10&#x0a;192.168.0.1; 1.1.1.7" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia10_02_Warning" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 10&#x0a;192.168.0.2; 1.1.1.7" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia20Warning" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 20&#x0a;192.168.0.1; 1.1.1.8" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia20_02_Warning" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 20&#x0a;192.168.0.2; 1.1.1.8" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="port1Warning" Width="620" Text="PORT 1 (Metro Ethernet)&#x0a;200.11.138.188" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="port2Warning" Width="620" Text="PORT 2 (Metro Ethernet)&#x0a;201.249.182.250" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="fibra200Warning" Width="620" Text="FIBRA 200Mbps&#x0a;201.249.133.34" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="fibra10Warning" Width="620" Text="FIBRA 10Mbps&#x0a;200.50.195.130" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </WrapPanel>
    </Canvas>
    <Label Grid.Row="3" Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvasDisconnected" Grid.Row="4" Background="Coral" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="canvasDisconnected_SizeChanged">
        <WrapPanel x:Name="panelDisconnected" Height="130"  Width="{Binding PanelDisconnectedWidth, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Canvas.Left="{Binding CanvasLeftDisconnected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Loaded="tb_Loaded">
            <WrapPanel.Resources>
                <Storyboard x:Key="slide3">
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="{Binding Width, ElementName=panelDisconnected}" Duration="{Binding TimeDisconnected, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="X"
                  Storyboard.TargetName="transferCurreny3"
                  RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </WrapPanel.Resources>
            <WrapPanel.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="transferCurreny3" X="0"/>
            </WrapPanel.RenderTransform>
            <WrapPanel.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="WrapPanel.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource slide3}" />
                </EventTrigger>
            </WrapPanel.Triggers>
            <TextBlock x:Name="macaracuayDisconnected" Width="620" Text="MACARACUAY&#x0a;10.0.1.11; 1.1.1.4" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="guacaraDisconnected" Width="620" Text="GUACARA&#x0a;10.0.1.11; 1.1.1.5" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia03Disconnected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 03&#x0a;192.168.0.1; 1.1.1.6" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia03_02_Disconnected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 03&#x0a;192.168.0.2; 1.1.1.6" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="agencia10Disconnected" Width="620" Text="AGENCIA 10&#x0a;192.168.0.1; 1.1.1.7" FontSize="50" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
        </WrapPanel>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

**Mainwindow**

```
using ClassLibraryBusiness;
using ClassLibraryMysql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

using static ClassLibraryBusiness.Connections;

namespace WpfAppConnectionCheck
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private Connections _connections = new Connections();
        private BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        public DataMain _dataMain = new DataMain();

        public MainWindow()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = _dataMain;
        InitializaListOFServers();
        tb_Loaded(null, null);
        UpdateScreenView();
        _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        _backgroundWorker.DoWork += _backgroundWorker_DoWork;
        _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
        _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 
    }

    private void _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object? sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Connections> connections = ((List<Connections>)e.UserState);

        foreach(var connection in connections)
        {
            if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.MACARACUAY)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    macaracuayConnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    macaracuayWarning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    macaracuayDisconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    macaracuayConnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    macaracuayWarning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    macaracuayDisconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    macaracuayConnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    macaracuayWarning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    macaracuayDisconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.GUACARA)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    guacaraConnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    guacaraWarning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    guacaraDisconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    guacaraConnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    guacaraWarning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    guacaraDisconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    guacaraConnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    guacaraWarning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    guacaraDisconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_03)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia03Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia03Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia03Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia03Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia03Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia03Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    agencia03Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia03Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia03Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_03_02)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia03_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia03_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia03_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia03_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia03_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia03_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    agencia03_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia03_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia03_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_10)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia10Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia10Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia10Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia10Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia10Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia10Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    agencia10Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia10Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia10Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_10_02)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia10_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia10_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia10_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia10_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia10_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia10_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    agencia10_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia10_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia10_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_20)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia20Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia20Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia20Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia20Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia20Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia20Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    agencia20Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia20Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia20Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_20_02)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia20_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia20_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia20_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    agencia20_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia20_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia20_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    agencia20_02_Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    agencia20_02_Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    agencia20_02_Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.PORT_1)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    port1Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    port1Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    port1Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    port1Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    port1Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    port1Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    port1Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    port1Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    port1Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
            else if (connection.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.PORT_2)
            {
                if (connection.Status == STATUS.CONNECTED)
                {
                    port2Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    port2Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    port2Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
                else if (connection.Status == STATUS.DISCONNECTED)
                {
                    port2Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    port2Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    port2Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    port2Connected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    port2Warning.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                    port2Disconnected.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }

        _dataMain.PanelConnectedWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelConnected.Children);
        _dataMain.PanelWarningWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelWarning.Children);
        _dataMain.PanelDisconnectedWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelDisconnected.Children);
        _dataMain.CanvasLeftConnected = -1 * GetPlusWhith(panelConnected.Children);
        _dataMain.CanvasLeftWarning = -1 * GetPlusWhith(panelWarning.Children);
        _dataMain.CanvasLeftDisconnected = -1 * GetPlusWhith(panelDisconnected.Children);
        _dataMain.TimeConnected = GetTimeForLength(-1 * _dataMain.CanvasLeftConnected);
        _dataMain.TimeWarning = GetTimeForLength(-1 * _dataMain.CanvasLeftWarning);
        _dataMain.TimeDisconnected = GetTimeForLength(-1 * _dataMain.CanvasLeftDisconnected);
    }

    private void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object? sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        
        while (true)
        {
            //CheckConnection().Wait();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }

    private async Task CheckConnection()
    {
        QueriesForConsult queriesForConsult = new QueriesForConsult();
        foreach(var item in Connections.ListOfConnections)
        {
            if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.MACARACUAY)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Macaracuay(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.GUACARA)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Guacara(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_03)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Agencia03(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_03_02)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Agencia03_02(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_10)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Agencia10(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_10_02)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Agencia10_02(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_20)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Agencia20(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.AGENCIA_20_02)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Agencia20_02(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.PORT_1)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Port_1(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.PORT_2)
            {
                await queriesForConsult.Port_2(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.FIBRA_200)
            {
                //await queriesForConsult.Fibra_200(item);
            }
            else if (item.NameServer == NAME_OF_SERVERS.FIBRA_10)
            {
                //await queriesForConsult.Fibra_10(item);
            }
        }

        _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0, Connections.ListOfConnections);
    }

    private void UpdateScreenView()
    {
        _dataMain.PanelConnectedWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelConnected.Children);
        _dataMain.PanelWarningWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelWarning.Children);
        _dataMain.PanelDisconnectedWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelDisconnected.Children);

        _dataMain.CanvasLeftConnected = -1 * GetPlusWhith(panelConnected.Children);
        _dataMain.CanvasLeftWarning = -1 * GetPlusWhith(panelWarning.Children);
        _dataMain.CanvasLeftDisconnected = -1 * GetPlusWhith(panelDisconnected.Children);

        _dataMain.TimeConnected = GetTimeForLength(-1 * _dataMain.CanvasLeftConnected);
        _dataMain.TimeWarning = GetTimeForLength(-1 * _dataMain.CanvasLeftWarning);
        _dataMain.TimeDisconnected = GetTimeForLength(-1 * _dataMain.CanvasLeftDisconnected);
    }

    private void tb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _dataMain.PanelConnectedWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelConnected.Children);
        _dataMain.PanelWarningWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelWarning.Children);
        _dataMain.PanelDisconnectedWidth = System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth + GetPlusWhith(panelDisconnected.Children);
    }

    private double GetPlusWhith(UIElementCollection childs)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i< childs.Count; i++)
        { 
            if (childs[i].Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            {
                result += 620;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I find the problem i am binding the property To of the DoubleAnimation, i am trying to figure it out